# Trying to join two tables together to have the unit_price vary based on the day

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have some code drafted but I'm not sure how to finish it, or if it needs more work. It looks like this.

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, pp.effective_date, pp.unit_price
from products p
inner join product_price pp
on p.product_id = pp.product_id
where (....stuck here)
```

Everything looks good, but how do I get the price to be based on the given effective date? The given effective date is 01/01/2021. I was thinking something maybe like this for the where:

```
where effective_date = 01/01/2021;
```

I'm not sure if this is correct though. I tried running it and similar where statements but nothing came of it.

Sample data:

**products**

```
P_id, p_name
11  ,  boys shorts
```

**product_price**

```
p_id, eff_date , unit_price
11  , 01-JAN-21, 10.48
```

I want the product’s price to now be a calculation based on a given date, using a join between Products and Product_Price.

[[image: This is what the tables look like]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added more to the question, does that help?

Comment: Imgaes of your tables does no good. We can't copy/paste from an image to create sample data. Please provide sample data and the desired output to your question. For more information, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576).

Comment: When you type where pp.effective_date = '2021-01-01' it will filter on that effective date. When you say "but nothing came of it", what exactly are your results? It is important that the products have entries in the product_price table for the effective date you are filtering on.

Comment: "sample data" means "please provide data that can be **easily** re-used", ideally this would be in the form of inserts, but anything that can easily be parsed into inserts is ok too. Try pasting the data tables now seen above into this url https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Comment: Apologies to everyone who has tried to help. I'm still kind of figuring a few things out on this site. The  csv-sql page that @Paul Maxwell suggested was a little confusing. I'm going to try and convert it though. I figured out why the date did not work, it was using the characters instead of the numeric value for the month. 01-JAN-2021 worked. I will be updating my question with my findings.

Comment: Would posting my sql statement for my tables work as the sample data and the sql statement for the data that is to be inserted into products in the question work? It would be quite large.

Comment: @starbyone I was able to get the data when I changed the date format. It gives me the item from the effective_date. Sorry I haven't been of much help off the bat. I did not know what was meant by "sample data". I could paste the sql statements if that is appropriate.

Comment: In Oracle you use date literals to suit `date` or you can specify the format you prefer using `to_date`. e.g. `to_date('01/01/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')`  will be the 1st of Jan 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When price data is stored with only a single date, it typically means "use this price from this date onward, but only up to the next date_effective".

The window function `row_number()` assigns an integer to each row, within a related `over clause`, `partition by` controls what is used to re-start numbering at 1 and an `order by` determines the sequence of rows and numbers within the partition. So by using a descending date order the most recent date per partition can be identified with a row number of 1.

If you couple this technique with a filter on the effective date being less than or equal to a given date, then the price that applies on the given date will be returned.:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, pp.effective_date, pp.unit_price
from products p
inner join (
           select
               product_price.*
             , row_number() over(partition by product_id order by effective_date DESC) as rn
           from product_price
           where effective_date <= to_date('01/01/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
           ) pp on p.product_id = pp.product_id
            and pp.rn = 1 /* only the relevant date/price is returned */
```

The second join condition could be used as a where condition instead

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name, pp.effective_date, pp.unit_price
from products p
inner join (
           select
               product_price.*
             , row_number() over(partition by product_id order by effective_date DESC) as rn
           from product_price
           where effective_date <= to_date('01/01/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
           ) pp on p.product_id = pp.product_id
where pp.rn = 1 /* only the relevant date/price is returned */
```

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS ( 
PRODUCT_ID      INTEGER, 
PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_PRICE ( 
PRODUCT_ID     INTEGER, 
EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE , 
UNIT_PRICE     DECIMAL(12,3));

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(100,'Product: 100');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(3412,'Product: 3412');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(1034,'Product: 1034');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(775522,'Product: 775522');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(101,'Product: 101');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(2342,'Product: 2342');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(8643,'Product: 8643');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(99771,'Product: 99771');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(2324,'Product: 2324');
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES(103,'Product: 102');

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(100, TO_DATE('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.12);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(101, TO_DATE('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.12);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(103, TO_DATE('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.12);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(1034, TO_DATE('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.12);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(2342, TO_DATE('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.12);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(3412, TO_DATE('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.12);

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(100, TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(101, TO_DATE('2020-11-11','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(103, TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(1034, TO_DATE('2020-11-11','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(2342, TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(3412, TO_DATE('2020-12-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(8643, TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(99771, TO_DATE('2021-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(2324, TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_PRICE VALUES(775522, TO_DATE('2021-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),10.43);
```

**Results**

```
+------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
| PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME  |    EFFECTIVE_DATE    | UNIT_PRICE |
+------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
|        100 | Product: 100  | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|        101 | Product: 101  | 2020-11-11T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|        103 | Product: 102  | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|       1034 | Product: 1034 | 2020-11-11T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|       2324 | Product: 2324 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|       2342 | Product: 2342 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|       3412 | Product: 3412 | 2020-12-01T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
|       8643 | Product: 8643 | 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z |      10.43 |
+------------+---------------+----------------------+------------+
```

see this working demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8a6c9/2

Comment: I think this helps with what I am looking for. I will update this post as I work through it. Thank you Paul for the help. Also thank you for explaining your code to me.

Comment: this is what we mean by "sample data", something we can work with , in the end this effort helps you get the answer faster, and it helps you by considering the sample data needed to prove a solution. e.g. one row of price data isn't enough

Comment: Okay, I will remember this for next time. I can understand any frustration that was had with me. Thank you all for the help. I think I am at a point where I can try other things in Oracle.